# Unable to run google app script due to access issues

Tags: google-apps-script, google-cloud-platform, authorization, http-status-code-404, google-cloud-console

I am trying to run google app script which uses AdminDirectory, AdminReports and AdminLIcenceManager Google API services. On running the script I am blocked with this error:

1. Access blocked: authorisation error
2. If you are a developer of Education License Manager, see error details

This app script is tied to google sheet and the result is to update the sheet based on the app script logic.

Error 400: admin_policy_enforced

I am not sure how to provide access to this app script. Or not entirely sure what has to be done to make this app script a trusted one.

This app script was shared to me from a different domain and I and trying to run this in my domain. I have the admin privileges.

I tried unrestricting the google app script runtime and app script api under SEcurity->API control->App access control->Google services. Doing this did not work.

I guess I need to make this app script as a recognized app, but again I am not sure what is the fix.